# How do I delete these files in the /root directory?

Tags: delete

I ran this command

```
sudo find / -type d -name '*Trash*' | sudo xargs du -h | sort
```

This was the output:

```
100M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.30
100M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.72
100M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.32
101M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.27
101M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.29
103M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.7
103M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.9
103M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.93
106M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.187
106M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.71
107M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.131
107M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.136
107M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.46
107M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.51
108M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.106
108M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.78
108M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.52
109M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.32
109M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.34
110M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.28
110M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.53
110M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.30
110M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.55
110M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.89
112M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.31
112M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.33
114M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.29
114M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.74
114M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.31
115M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.125
117M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.83
118M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.105
118M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.70
119M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.133
1.1G    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.148
11M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.179
1.1M    /root/.local/share/Trash/info
122M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.80
124M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.137
125G    /root/.local/share/Trash
125G    /root/.local/share/Trash/files
125M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.49
129M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.153
1.2G    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.165
1.2G    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.166
12K /media/A80E1DE60E1DAE76/.Trash-1000/files
12M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.178
12M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.180
12M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.181
130M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.85
137M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.5
137M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.7
137M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.76
13M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.143
13M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.18
13M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.182
13M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.16
13M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.2
13M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.4
140M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.77
145M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.63
147M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.43
147M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.45
148M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.84
149M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.160
149M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.79
1.4G    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.191
150M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.26
150M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.28
153M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.64
153M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.78
154M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.107
155M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.80
155M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.79
15M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.151
162M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.65
163M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.82
164M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.104
165M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.39
165M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.41
168M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.62
16M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.171
170M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.135
170M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.159
171M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.91
172M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.41
172M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.43
175M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.33
175M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.35
176M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.76
179M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.38
179M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.40
179M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.61
1.7G    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.167
17M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.172
180M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.186
181M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.71
182M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.158
183M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.59
185M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.123
189M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.92
18M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.142
18M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.149
18M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.150
18M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.152
18M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.173
18M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.177
191M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.147
193M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.102
195M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.73
196M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.94
198M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.58
19M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.175
19M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.176
205M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.108
206M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.56
206M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.60
207M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.55
209M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.90
2.0G    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.190
20K /media/A80E1DE60E1DAE76/.Trash-1000/info
20M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.17
20M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.15
210M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.121
211M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.134
212M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.57
21M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.174
223M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.88
225M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.118
230M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.87
232M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.66
235M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.139
236M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.97
238M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.54
240M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.163
241M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.126
242M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.81
243M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.156
244M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.37
244M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.39
248M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.110
249M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.75
256M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.73
257M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.64
25M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.10
25M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.8
262M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.86
266M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.144
27M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.99
282M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.127
29M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.183
29M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.22
29M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.20
316M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.124
31M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.21
31M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.23
320M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.168
32M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.12
32M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.10
334M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.140
338M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.69
33M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.21
33M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.19
340M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.57
341M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.185
342M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.169
343M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.129
346M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.111
348M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.103
351M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.34
351M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.36
352M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.155
358M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.59
36G /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.1
36G /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2
36M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.120
36M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.24
36M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.51
36M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.26
37M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.112
390M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.162
398M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.67
39M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.145
401M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.52
402M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.54
408M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.40
408M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.42
4.0K    /home/daniel/.local/share/Trash
40K /media/A80E1DE60E1DAE76/.Trash-1000
41M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.13
41M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.11
428M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.61
434M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.36
434M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.38
43M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.19
43M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.17
43M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.53
440M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.157
448M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.35
448M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.37
44M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.20
44M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.18
454M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.116
47M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.11
47M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.9
48M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.48
495M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.192
49M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.114
49M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.50
52M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.3
538M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.68
53M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.95
54M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.98
551M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.63
57M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.101
5.7M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.119
57M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.14
57M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.12
581M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.70
586M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.170
588M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.62
58M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.4
58M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.42
58M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.44
58M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.6
59M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.22
59M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.24
603M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.109
60M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.15
60M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.13
619M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.154
61M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.23
61M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.25
626M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.138
62M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.3
62M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.5
63M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.188
64M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.1
65M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.113
65M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.146
69M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.122
701M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.60
71M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.130
71M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.141
72M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.132
72M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.47
74M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.16
74M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.14
74M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.25
74M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.45
74M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.27
74M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.47
751M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.164
752M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.128
76M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.49
77M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.115
77M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.77
8.0K    /media/A80E1DE60E1DAE76/.Trash-1000/expunged
810M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.58
815M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.66
818M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.56
82M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.44
82M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.46
835M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.68
84M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.189
860M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.161
86M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.117
86M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.69
86M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.75
90M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.74
924M    /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.184
94M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.81
95M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.100
96M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.6
96M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.65
96M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.8
97M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.2.50
97M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.67
97M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.72
98M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.96
99M /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir.48
```

How do I delete these files?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `sudo rm -fr /root/.local/share/Trash/files/recup_dir*`for the ones in recup_dir folders?. The same for others that appear.

UPDATE -

If you really want to delete all of them AND you are sure they will not create any problem with the system or that you have additional files with the "Trash" word in them (Like music or video files), then you can do the following:

`sudo find / -type d -name '*Trash*' -exec rm -fr {} \;`

This will delete EVERYTHING with the name "Trash" in them in every place that is mounted.

If you get an error like the following:

```
find: `/home/cyrex/.local/share/Trash': No such file or directory   
find: `/media/cyrex/xtreme/.Trash-1000': No such file or directory
```

it means that a previous delete already eliminated the Folder, so the rest that were found in the same folder are already gone. No need to worry about this.

You can double check if everything was deleted by executing the command again.

This will create a problem with the Trash Can icon in Unity since it will still show as FULL.

Comment: is there any way i could delete them all at once? I have over 100 folders.

Comment: Updated to include a way to delete (Similar to green7) but also warnings that you should know.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple:

```
sudo find / -type d -name 'Trash' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

More information:

- http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-how-to-find-and-remove-files/
- http://gerardmcgarry.com/blog/linux-using-find-utility-with-regex-delete-files

Comment: when i tried that it said

find: `/home/daniel/.local/share/Trash': No such file or directory
find: `/root/.local/share/Trash': No such file or directory

Comment: Should this be '\*Trash*' ?